# How to stop javascript from Multiple alerts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

```
    $('#ms_cats_meta_eduyear, #ms_cats_meta_semester, #ms_cats_meta_subject').change(function () {



                $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                $('#save-post').removeClass('button-disabled');

                $('input#publish').click( function () {
                    var eduyear_val = $("#ms_cats_meta_eduyear").val();
                    var semester_val = $('#ms_cats_meta_semester').val();
                    var subject_val = $("#ms_cats_meta_subject").val();

                    if (eduyear_val == -1 || semester_val == -1 || subject_val == -1){
                        var msg= "من فضلك تأكد من ادخال جميع حقول اختيار التصنيف.";
                        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                        alert(msg);
                        return false;

                    }else{
                        $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                        $('#save-post').removeClass('button-disabled');

                        return true;
                    }

                });

});
```

I'm using the function to produce an alert if the user tries to submit the form with the value of a three select boxes is -1. The Alert appears more than one time increasingle on making changes to the select box value, any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Is this really the code? You have a local function inside of a change() event? And based on your example, it never gets called. I'm confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, the right code is above.

Comment: Your code is a little wonky.. Why is verifyCats inside your anonymous function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a click event inside the change event, that is, every time the change event is triggered a new click event is created (in addition to those already created before).

Just move the click event outside the change event.